# How to conditionally remove first line only with sed when it matches?

Tags: sed

Can I use `sed` to check the first line of some command's output (to stdout) and delete this very first line if it matches a certain pattern?

Say, the command's output is something like this:

```
"AB"
"CD"
"E"
"F"
```

I want it to become:

```
"CD"
"E"
"F"
```

But when the first line is `"GH"`, I don't want to delete the line.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<some_command> |sed '1/<pattern>/d'
```

The shell told me:

```
sed: 0602-403 1/<pattern>/d is not a recognized function.
```

I only want to use sed to process the first line, leaving the other lines untouched.

What is the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sed -e '1!b' -e '/GH/!d' file
```

Comment: It works! I guess here `1` means the line number, but what does `!b` mean? Also, can these two expressions be merged into one (using only one `-e`)?

Comment: @QiangXu, yes `1` is the first line, `!` means `if not` and `b` is a `break` command which all means `if not line 1 bail out and continue with the next line`. For the first line only `/GH/!d` means `if the line doesn't contain GH delete it`. Some sed's allow the use of the `;` character as a way to join commands, with `BSD` or `Apple` your success may vary.

Comment: In `man sed`, it only tells me `b[label] Branches to the : command bearing the label variable. If the label variable is empty, it branches to the end of the script.` The manual didn't mention `b` as a break command. Yet, it works this way. Anything I missed?

Comment: This solution only applies to the very specific example of OP. Skipping the first first and deleting it if it matches the pattern. It doesn't combine well with other sed logic. `0 , /pattern/ d` is correct

Comment: @potong I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're trying to say. Perhaps my comment was unclear. This sed script skips all other commands if it's not the first line. Otherwise, it deletes the line if it matches the pattern. This method works if the only purpose of your script is to do exactly that. `1 { /pattern/ d }` on the other hands let's you combine other commands for the remainder of the input

Comment: @CervEd my fault not yours. The solution is stand alone not to be used in conjunction with other sed commands. With GNU sed something like `sed '1{/GH/!d}; more sed commands' file` would be suffice but `{` , `}` and `;` do not behave the same for all variations of sed.

Comment: @potong that's a fair point. I suppose it's a valid solution to pipe this into another sed if it has better compatibility

Answer (score 7):

You want to reference the 1st line, then say delete:

```
$ sed '1 d' file
```

No need for any pattern if you know which line you want to delete.

With a pattern, use this syntax:

```
$ sed '0,/pattern/ d' file
```

Comment: No, I want to delete the first line, only if there is a certain pattern in it.

Comment: No error spit out, but it still doesn't work. The first line doesn't get deleted.

Comment: Do you see the 1st line when you do `sed /pattern/ file`?

Comment: No: `sed: 0602-403 /<pattern>/ is not a recognized function.` But, if I use `sed 's/<pattern>/<something>/'`, it would replace the matched pattern successfully.

Comment: Ah! Yes, you need a command such as p: `sed /pattern1/p file` -- if the s command works, though, it should be a good match... May we see the actual pattern? (could you add it to your post?) The 0,/pattern/ address works well for me!

Comment: Yes, I could see the pattern with the `p` command. The pattern itself is `/" "$/`, meaning to match a space character surrounded by double quotes. Probably your solution would work with GNU sed, but my sed is inborn with AIX machine. Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: Ah! You did not specify that it was AIX. Yes... The addresses support are for some GNU extensions. I'm not sure that would work on a more standard sed.

Comment: Address 0 doesn't work on POSIX. It is a GNU feature. POSIX sed address range has to match a minimum of 2 lines because it turns on a flag on the first line and turns it off on the second. See:
https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html
https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#toc-uh-29

Comment: @dosentmatter `1 { /pattern/ d }` maybe?

Answer (score 4):

This is what you want:

```
$ sed '1{/"GH"/!d}' file
```

Comment: It doesn't work, though: `sed: 0602-404 Function 1{/<pattern>/d} cannot be parsed.` I used `"GH"` as an example, and want to focus on the pattern I need to match. That's why I used `d`, instead of `!d`.

Comment: Then you have a backlevel sed.  Try putting newlines after the `{` and before the `}`.

Comment: @jthill: Still not working: `sed: 0602-404 Function 1{\n/<pattern>/d\n} cannot be parsed.` My `sed` is from AIX machine, not a GNU one, :(

Comment: For BSD sed you need a semicolon after commands in brackets: `sed '1{/"GH"/!d;}' file` works

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '1{/<pattern>/{/GH/!d}}' input
```

The error in your expression can be fixed like this:

```
sed '1{/<pattern>/d}' input
```