# Sed & Mac OS Terminal: How to remove parentheses content from the first line of every file?

Tags: macos, sed, terminal

I am on Mac Os 10.14.6 and have a directory that contains subdirectories that all contain text files. Altogether, there are many hundreds of text files.

I would like to go through the text files and check for any content in the first line that is in parentheses. If such content is found, then the parentheses (and content in the parentheses) should be removed.

**Example:**

Before removal:

```
The new world (82 edition)
```

After removal:

```
The new world
```

How would I do this?

---

**Steps I have tried:**

Google around, it seems SED would be best for this.
I have found [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14838/sed-one-liner-to-delete-everything-between-a-pair-of-brackets), which provides SED code for removing bracketed content.

```
sed -e 's/([^()]*)//g'
```

However, I am not sure how to adapt it to work on multiple files and also to limit it to the first line of those files. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126479/how-to-conditionally-remove-first-line-only-with-sed-when-it-matches) which explains how to use SED on multiple files, but I am not sure how to adapt the example to work with parentheses content.

Please note: As long as the solution works on Mac OS terminal, then it does not need to use SED. However, from Googling, SED seems to be the most suited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve what you're after simply by using a bash script and sed together, as so:

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in $PWD/*.txt; do
    sed -i '' '1 s/([^()]*)//g' $filename
done
```

The script simply iterates over all the `.txt` files in $PWD (the current working directory, so that you can add this script to your bin and run it anywhere), and then runs the command

```
sed -ie '1 s/([^()]*)//g' $filename
```

on the file. By starting the command with the number `1` we tell sed to only work on the first line of the file :)

**Edit: Best Answer**

The above works fine in a directory where all contained objects are files, and not including directories; in other words, the above does not perform recursive search through directories.

Therefore, after some research, this command should perform exactly what the question asks:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec sed -i '' '1 s/([^()]*)//g' {} \;
```

I **must** iterate, and reiterate, that you test this on a backup first to test it works. Otherwise, use the same command as above but change the '' in order to control the creation of backups. For example,

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec sed -i '.bkp' '1 s/([^()]*)//g' {} \;
```

This command will perform the sed replace in the original file (keeping the filename) but will create a backup file for each with the appended `.bkp`, for example `test1.txt` becomes `test1.txt.bkp`. This a safer option, but choose what works best for you :)

Comment: Thanks! By  `"add this script to your bin"` do you mean I need to put it in `/usr/local/bin`. Also, do I need to give it a special filename and extension? I added it to  `/usr/local/bin` as `remove-brackets` (no extension), and when I run it in the terminal, it says `sed: -i may not be used with stdin`. This happens if I try it on the main directory that contains all the subdirectories, or if I try it directly on a subdirectory. Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: @big_smile I've updated the script. It now won't create backups of the files ending with .txte, like it did before... oops. As for the `sed: -i may not be used with stdin`, I'm not sure why you're getting this. I'm running OS X too. Try again with the new script I've put up, but if you could also provide part of an `ls -l` command result so I can see what the file structure is actually like I'd appreciate it. Also, yes, I meant add to `/usr/local/bin`. That name is perfect, no file extension and make sure to `chmod 755 remove-brackets`!

Comment: Still getting the same error message, even with new script. Just to double check, when you say "add script to bin," you mean in `/usr/local/bin`. Also, do I need to give it a special filename and extension?  Here is the `ls -l` command results: https://pastebin.com/U3EDRrtE


Thanks for your continued help.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I went down the rabbit hole with find, xargs and sed. As I stated in my previous comment, yes, you're correct to put it in in `/usr/local/bin` and you do not need it to have a special filename or extension. You only need to make sure you `chmod 755` it so that is executable. Thanks for the results of `ls -l`, that really helped. One more question: do your text files have spaces in them, like `file 1.txt` instead of `file1.txt`?

Comment: @big_smile I have edited my answer to provide a single line script which should perform exactly what you're after. If it does, please accept my solution, otherwise let me know and I'd be happy to help you further! :)

Answer (score 1):

Good try,

The command you where looking for single line:

```
sed -E '1s|\([^\)]+\)||'
```

The command to replace each input file first line:

```
sed -Ei '1s|\([^\)]+\)||' *.txt
```

#### example:

```
echo "The new world (82 edition)" |sed -E '1s|\([^\)]+\)||'
The new world
```

#### Explanation

`sed -Ei`  `E` option: the extended RegExp syntax, `i` option: for in-place file replacement

`sed -Ei '1s|match RegExp||'` for first line only, replace first matched RegExp string with empty string

`\([^\)]+\)` RegExp matching: start with `(`, `[^\)]`any char not `)`, `+` - more than once, terminate with `)`

Comment: Thanks! When I try that code on the main directory, that contains all the sub directories, it states `sed: 1: "*.txt": invalid command code *`. And when I try it directly on a sub directroy, it states `sed: 1: "<<First line>>": invalid command code A`. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: fixed the answer. Line number to precede the `s` command with no space. Try again.

Comment: Just so you know: Using on the main directory gives this error message `sed: 1: "*.txt": invalid command code *`. Using on the sub directory gives this error message `sed: 1: "<<First line>>...": invalid command code A`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# create a temporary file
tmp=$(mktemp)

# for each something in _the current directory_
for i in *; do
    # if it is not a file, don't parse it
    if [ ! -f "$i" ]; then continue; fi
    # remove parenthesis on first line, save the output in temporary file
    sed '1s/([^)]*)//g' "$i" > "$tmp"
    # move temporary file to the original file
    mv "$tmp" "$i"
done

# remove temporary file
rm "$tmp"
```

Comment: Do I put this in the bin. If so, what command do I use in the terminal? Thanks!